# How to go through array in a specific order

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to set indexes in a int array in a specific order. The order is going backwards every 8 indices, looks something like this:

```
7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
15 14 13 12 11 10 9  8
23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16
etc.
```

Code (it's not important that I'm setting the indices to be equal to j * 100, I just want to go in the right order in the array):

```cpp
int size = 3;
const int len = 8;
int *arr = new int[size * len];
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for(int j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      arr[(len - j - 1) * (i + 1)] = j * 100;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would be glad if my answer helped you in solving your problem. Could you upvote my answer, please? Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To traverse the array in the specific order you described, you can modify the inner loop to calculate the index using both i and j. Here's the modified code:

```cpp
int size = 3;
const int len = 8;
int *arr = new int[size * len];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        arr[i * len + (len - j - 1)] = j * 100;
    }
}
```

In this modified code, the index is calculated as `i * len + (len - j - 1)` to achieve the specific order you want.